# Website store JS and CSS on client side without any framework

Tags: codeigniter, angularjs

I am making a website in Codeigniter and not using any client side framework like angularJS. However I need some features of angularJS like downloading the JS and CSS once at the client rather than downloading it for each page. As my website content is much dependent on the server, should I use angularJS? I read that it makes tha application slower.

Comment: Cache static files in the browser via `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not about angular at all!

I recommend you to read something about build systems like require, grunt, yeoman...

Comment: yes my question isn't exactly about angularJS but angular does the task of downloading all JS and CSS at once. So should I use angularJS for my website or will it just increase the load?

Comment: no, your should not use Angular for this task. It's quite heavy framework

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is ajaxifying your website, as Stever said it's not about angular at all..

you may use RequireJS to load the script when a page need it.

For a best perfomance, use grunt for running any task like : minifying, compressing your stylesheet and so on..